# How to set tranparency for one image only in openGL ES in Android?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I code game on Android where I have several sprites.

My goal is to set `gl.glColor4f(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.2f)` a.e. transparency only for specific image. (I don't like Photoshop).

In my case its  image that represents a "number" and moves up and begin to be transparent till disappear at all.

However, when I use it, I see that all sprite images are transparent or not what I want.

What I do wrong? Does my code seem right? (i'm junior in OPenGL)

Here is relevant part of code:

**Renderer**

```
@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig confid) {
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);
    //gl.glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
    //gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
    gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);
    gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    gl.glTexEnvf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE,                /*GL10.GL_REPLACE*/ GL10.GL_MODULATE);  
}
```

**[text sprite image]**

```
gl.glPushMatrix();
try {
    float transx = ...'
    float transy = ...;

    gl.glTranslatef(transx, transy, 0.0f);

    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, floatBufferArray[mFrame]);


    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, vertices.length / 3);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    gl.glColor4f(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.2f); // <---- alpha 0.2f
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
   Log.e("Fess", e.getMessage());
}
gl.glPopMatrix();
```

**[other sprite images with alpha 1f]**

```
gl.glPushMatrix();
try {
    float transx = ...'
    float transy = ...;

    gl.glTranslatef(transx, transy, 0.0f);

    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, floatBufferArray[mFrame]);


    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, vertices.length / 3);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    gl.glColor4f(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f);
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
   Log.e("Fess", e.getMessage());
}
gl.glPopMatrix();
```

and this is how im load them:

```
public void loadTextures(GL10 gl, Context context) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "ExplosionSprite :: loadTextures");  

    mFrame = 0;

    InputStream is;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    is = context.getResources().openRawResource(DRAW_SOURCE);


    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    try {
        is.close();
        is = null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }

    gl.glGenTextures(TEXTURE_COUNT, textures, 0);

    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

    bitmap.recycle(); 

}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried calling glColor4f(1,1,1,1) after you have drawn the image? You have to do that to reset the drawing color back to solid.

EDIT: Now that I read your code more carefully, it seems that you set the color only AFTER you have drawn the sprites. Call the glColor function before glDrawArrays, and it should work.

Comment: thank you mate, works like charm, it ran away from me about to set alpaha before `GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY`